# I have Bundler 2, yet Ruby/Rails says is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rails-spring

Booting up localhost, I type in 'rails s' into my terminal. I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    4: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    3: from /Users/macbookpro/flippingUnleashedCRM/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /Users/macbookpro/flippingUnleashedCRM/bin/spring:10:in `new'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
```

So, I type in `bundler --version` to see what I am using. The result is:

```
Bundler version 2.2.11
```

I take a look in my Gemfile.lock, I scroll down, and I see:

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.1p57

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.11
```

What the heck is the problem?

Comment: Not sure, but the error is for Ruby 2.6 (`Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6`) and your Gemfile.lock is for Ruby 2.5.1. Try stopping your [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) server. You might also have outdated spring wrappers. Try [removing](https://github.com/rails/spring#removal) and reinstalling them.

Comment: ^ What worked for me was bypassing Spring. I followed steps 1 and 2 from this link and it worked. Thanks for giving some good pointers. 

https://fuzzyblog.io/blog/rails/2017/03/20/disabling-spring-in-rails.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a couple things could be going wrong here:

To potentially resolve your immediate issue, try running `bundle exec rails s`. This will run rails in the [context of your bundle](https://bundler.io/v2.2/man/bundle-exec.1.html).

Secondly, you should also make sure your Ruby version matches the version specified. Like another comment mentioned, you seem to be running on Ruby 2.6 on a project that is on Ruby 2.5. A Ruby version manager like [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) will help you manage your Ruby versions and gem dependencies on each version better.